# Issue with using cloudstorage module in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cloud-storage

I am trying to upload directly to Google Cloud Storage from a series of URLs. I have been trying to implement the solution form here:
[How to upload an image from web into Google Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623315/how-to-upload-an-image-from-web-into-google-cloud-storage/27624158#27624158?newreg=d80be224c6994787be84bf0bd2be895a)

In particular, whenever I try to open a file using cloudstorage module,

```
options={'x-goog-acl': 'public-read', 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0, no-transform'}
with gcs.open(filename, 'w', content_type=content_type, options=options) as f:
    f.write(image_bytes)
```

I get the following error:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-dec1a5d39c62> in <module>()
     18 
     19 options={'x-goog-acl': 'public-read', 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0, no-transform'}
---> 20 with gcs.open(filename, 'w', content_type=content_type, options=options) as f:
     21     f.write(image_bytes)
     22     f.close()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'
```

I have already tried installing cloudstorage in an isolated environment but still had no luck.

Based on the reference below, cloudstorage.open() exist in 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions

Any idea where the problem could be?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps check a working example at [Write a CSV to store in Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39525052/11154841).

Answer (score 2):

do `print dir(gcs)` to see what is in there. you may be installing a similarly named but different package.

It sounds like this is the one you want

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/tree/master/python/src/cloudstorage

and this is the function you are trying to use:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/master/python/src/cloudstorage/cloudstorage_api.py#L47

The readme.md for this repo points here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage

which says to do this:

`pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient -t <your_app_directory/lib>`

Comment: Thank you very much Alex! It seems I was using a wrong library.

Comment: It has issues with python3 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560171/import-cloudstorage-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax